# How can I create a general page, that I can use every where inside the app using Thymleaf and Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to understand how use Thymeleaf, I have a structure like this:

I have a `default.html` that work like the most general page, I put there some inclusion like general `css`, `bootstrap` and so on.. The I replace using `th:replace` the footer and a navbar. I use this page as base line for all the other pages.

My problem is: how can I use this page for all the other pages?

For example if I have 2 pages, page **A** and **B** and both of them need bootstrap, the app's css and so on, I don't want write the code to include them twice, but only once. So to do that I think I have to put page **A** inside default.html if I want show **A** and **B** in the other case.

At least, I done in this way using JSP.

How can I do it? Is it possible using Thymeleaf?

I tried to do somenthig like that but id doesn't work

**DEFAULT.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
  <title th:text="#{application_name}"></title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" th:href="@{/static/favicon.ico}"/>

  <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/mio.css}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css}"/>
</head>

<body>

<div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    <p>Your page content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is totally possible!**

We have some steps to do it with Thymeleaf:

**Configurations:**

1 - Include the thymeleaf layout dialect into your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2 - I do not know how is your webConfig, but with Spring, we have to add this configuration to template engine:

```
@Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

        //your templateResolver
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        //here it is!
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());

        return engine;
    }
```

**The default html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"

    <!-- Necessary to thymeleaf layout dialect-->
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/layout/stylesheets/vendors/bootstrap.css}" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>your Heder here</header>

    <!--Here what you want, it gonna find the other html that contains "maincode"-->
    <section layout:fragment="maincode"></section>

    <footer>yourFooter</footer> 

    <script th:src="@{/javascript/vendors/jquery-2.2.4.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/layout/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

    <th:block layout:fragment="javascript-extra"></th:block>
</body>

</html>
```

**The other html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt" xmlns="http://w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"

    <!--Tell who is the default html-->
    layout:decorate="layout/defaultHtml">

<body>

    <section layout:fragment="maincode">
        bla bla bla
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Any question, just ask!

Comment: Is there a reason to use section instead of div for example?? And I saw also the command layou:decorator, what is the difference between it and decorate?

Comment: 1 - For good practices I used "section", but you can use whatever you want; 2 - No difference, just the name, was a updated to better the pattern: https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/issues/95